# How to close .csv file that was opened outside of the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, window

I am currently using Raspian OS and Libre Office. I'm using Python 3.
I'm trying to create a RFID door lock that logs each user that enters.

The issue i'm having is, if someone leaves the .csv file open after look at the log, my script cannot write to it. so it throws an error. I would like my script to close the currently open instance(window) with that file opened, then I can have the script open and write to the file.

The file is located in the same folder as my python script.

I have tried:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /IM Entry_Log.csv")
```

with no luck.

This is the function I have right now. I need to close the file in my exception statement.

```
def unlockDoor(x):
    #Add GPIO Output here later
    while True:
        try:
            userDictionary = shelve.open("User_Dictionary")
            print('Welcome,', userDictionary[x])
            print('Door Unlocked')
            with open("Entry_Log.csv", "a") as log:
                log.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S"), x, userDictionary[x]))
            userDictionary.close()
        except:
            #close the open window for "Entry_Log.csv" here <--
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `TASKKILL` is a windows command line command, not a linux one. You may try a linux equivalent command

Comment: Ok, ill search for equivalent. Does anyone know what this equivalent might be?

Comment: `pkill` I guess

Comment: everything I see for `pkill` suggests that is to stop other python scripts, not to close files.

Comment: What about `os.kill(pid,sig)`. Not sure what the pid and sig need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me on Linux, using the `psutil` package. When the file can't be opened a search is made to find all other processes that have the file open, and these are sent a terminate signal.

NB this works only if the calling process has the correct permissions.

```
import psutil
import sys
import os
import signal

def terminate_others(pattern):
    pids = psutil.pids();
    for pid in pids:
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        try:
            flist = p.open_files()
            if flist:
                for f in flist:
                    if pattern in f.path:
                        print "Terminating " + repr(pid)
                        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        except:
            pass


fname = "Entry_Log.csv"

try:
    with open(fname, "a") as log:
        log.write("Some log text")
except:
    print "error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    # close other processes that have this file open
    terminate_others(fname)
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: I will definitely try this and get back to you soon